# Firebase query limitToLast() + last time stamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if there's a way I can query this.
In the following example I have a list of attendance dates.  As you can see 2-11 is added to firebase before 2-2.

[image]

I had a call where I was doing: firebase.

```
this.props.firebase.getLastAttendanceDate(organization)
.limitToLast(1)
.once('value')
```

With the above I would always get the last record created in my firebase db.  However this threw me off since 2-11 is no longer the last.  Is there anyway to do something like this:

```
this.props.firebase.getLastAttendanceDate(organization)
.limitToLastCreated
.once('value')
```

Obviously the above won't work.  Only an example.
Any ideas?

Comment: One standard approach when you want to sort dates is to use the following format: YYYYMMDD. This way the alphabetical order corresponds to the date order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a date as a sortable string key, you should use a date format that sorts both lexicographically.  This means your date strings should have the largest units first, and you should zero-pad the units so that the strings are always the same length.  For example, "2020-02-09-PM".  If you don't do this, then your date strings will simply never sort the way you expect, no matter what you do with the query.

Also note that, with the format "YYYY-MM-DD-AM", you are depending on "AM" sorting before "PM", which it does.  But you are probably better off using numbers rather than strings in this case.